# Getting error: cannot spawn .husky/pre-commit: No such file or directory when trying to commit, previously ran npm install

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, node.js, git

I'm having this issue with my computer when trying to commit.

This happens after I run `npm install` for a recently created project.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I'm posting here cuz I couldn't find anything to fix this.

---

## Edit #1

This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "salesforce-app",
"private": true,
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Salesforce App",
"scripts": {
  "lint": "npm run lint:lwc && npm run lint:aura",
  "lint:aura": "eslint **/aura/**",
  "lint:lwc": "eslint **/lwc/**",
  "test": "npm run test:unit",
  "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
  "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
  "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
  "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage",
  "prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
  "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
  "postinstall": "husky install",
  "precommit": "lint-staged"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc": "^1.0.1",
  "@prettier/plugin-xml": "^0.13.1",
  "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc": "^2.0.0",
  "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura": "^2.0.0",
  "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-lightning": "^0.1.1",
  "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.13.0",
  "eslint": "^7.29.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
  "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
  "husky": "^6.0.0",
  "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
  "prettier": "^2.3.1",
  "prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.9.1"
},
"lint-staged": {
  "**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}": [
    "prettier --write"
  ],
  "**/{aura,lwc}/**": [
    "eslint"
  ]
}
```

}

Comment: What's your package.json look like?

Comment: @sfdcfox I updated the question, thanks for checking this... I also have another question without an answer which I think you could help me with (not meant to have you giving me all the solutions, just that I hit a blocker on that one too). Thanks again

Comment: Odd, the old setup seems to work just fine, but for some reason, this new package.json doesn't seem to. Might need to get in touch with the DX team.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the feedback, should I get in touch, or are you gonna report that issue?

Comment: Say, do you have a .husky/pre-commit file in your workspace?

Comment: I'll try and see what I can find, but you should definitely try to reach out, too. My days are kind of busy, I might not be able to get back to it for a while.

Comment: I just tested this:

Created the project using `sfdx:project:create`, initialized a github repo using `git init`, created git repo using `gh repo create`, added files using `git add .`, committed changes via `git commit -m "<MSG>"`, it worked fine, then I ran `npm install`, made some changes and repeated the process to commit and it errored.

@sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to do your commit, throw a --no-verify switch onto the commit command: `git commit -m "<MSG>" --no-verify`